# Using ARD to do mass upgrades?

Tags: macos, command-line, upgrade, apple-remote-desktop

I am trying to find a method of Upgrading many computers, for example to 10.10.x to 10.12.x . Is there a way of doing so using Apple Remote Desktop? Planning to update about 40 computers.

I am able to update from 10.12.4 to 10.12.5 but so far I have not made much progress with an upgrade. Would AutoDMG be a step forward without deleting the files already on the computers?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do a *major* upgrade to all your clients remotely?  What you need to keep in mind is that these machines will be unusable from anywhere to 30 mins to an hour and nothing irks an end user more than showing up to get some work done and the machine can't be used because it's updating.

Comment: This will be on an off day, so no users will be affected. I intend to test with a small number of computers (5 at most). Off day being Friday or Saturday night. If all works well I plan to do rolling upgrades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Apple Remote Desktop to copy the macOS Installer application to the Applications folder on every client Mac, then send the following UNIX command as root:

```
/Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app --agreetolicense --nointeraction
```

This command starts the in-place upgrade action to macOS High Sierra. It may take some time for the entire process to complete, but it doesn't require any user interaction.

Comment: This is exactly what I did after some serious searching.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a package and deploy it, but it will not be simple. I would look at using something like JAMF for managing that many computers.